# VSTS - build definition error in solution file

Tags: azure-devops

This is probably something simple that I am doing wrong as I am new to VSTS.

I have uploaded my existing .NET website project to VSTS and when I run a build definition in VSTS, I get an error in the solution file.

I can see what the problem is....the solution file has the pathway of the project on my PC in it...which is stored in inetpub/wwwroot/VSProjects on my PC.

Is there something simple I am missing to avoid this? There is probably a certain way that a .net website should be uploaded to vsts to avoid this pathway error?

Thanks for any help...

Here are the build solution log errors -

```
2018-01-19T16:34:14.3619604Z   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_compiler.exe -v /PropertyRegister -p ..\..\..\..\..\..\inetpub\wwwroot\VSProjects\PropertyRegister\ -u -f PrecompiledWeb\PropertyRegister\ 
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1411730Z ##[error]ASPNETCOMPILER(0,0): Error 1003: The directory 'd:\inetpub\wwwroot\VSProjects\PropertyRegister\' doesn't exist.
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1419278Z ASPNETCOMPILER : error 1003: The directory 'd:\inetpub\wwwroot\VSProjects\PropertyRegister\' doesn't exist. [d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.metaproj]
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1806460Z Done Building Project "d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.metaproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1818301Z Done Building Project "d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1837158Z 
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1837587Z Build FAILED.
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1873374Z 
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1882800Z "d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.sln" (default target) (1) ->
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1884216Z (ValidateProjects target) ->
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1885795Z   d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.sln.metaproj : warning MSB4121: The project configuration for project "PropertyRegister" was not specified in the solution file for the solution configuration "Release|Any CPU". [d:\a\3\s\PropertyRegister\PropertyRegister.sln]
2018-01-19T16:34:16.1886267Z
```

Comment: There are hardcoded references to the local paths specific to your environment in your solution file. Find it out, replace with the relative paths (or remove if not required) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

In VS Build task, you should **specify the `publishproj` file instead of `sln` in Solution option of the VS Build task** for your website project.

You can specify the detail relative path for the `publishproj` file or use wildcards to match the website project you want to build as below examples:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why? This fixed my issue but I really would like to know why they default the project to build the .sln if it really should be pointed at publishproj